# Arduino Ports Bitschift

Tags: c++, c, arduino, bit-shift

Do you know the bouncing red light of the Knight-Rider car? I am building something like that with my Arduino. I've got an Arduino Uno with 7 leds.

The problem I have is with the bitshifts. When my program is running, I tell it to give power to the pins with this:

```
PORTD = 0b00000001;
```

After a little delay, I have to switch the power to another pin. So it has to be something like this:

```
PORTD = 0b00000010;
```

It is possible to archive this with bit shifts. I though about something like this, but it isn't working:

```
PORTD = PORTD << 1;
```

How can I fix the problem that I've got?

This is my code for now, I have to add the bitshift:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main()
{
    UCSR0B = 0;             
    DDRD = 0b11111111;  

    for(;;)
    {
        PORTD = 0b10000000; 
        _delay_ms(200); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this fairly easily if you have `stdout`: the first one is decimal 1 and the second is decimal 2.  So `int x = 1; x <<= 1; printf("%d", x);` will demonstrate whether the bitshift worked or not.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the avr-gcc libraries directly instead of the Arduino libraries?

Comment: Yes, this is because of school. ;-) I can use <arduino.h> isn't it? But when I include that, it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by combining all kinds of answer you all gived me and some advice of my teacher.

I've made two unsigned chars. One for a if statement to determine if we are going up or down, the other one for telling which led is on. Then I've made some if statements in my loop. You can see it below.

I am doing this in my for loop:

1) If we are going up (updown is 1), set light up 1 higher. If the light is bigger than or 7, set updown to 0.

2) Else set light up 1 down. If the light is 0, set updown to 1.

3) Do the bitshift.

4) Do a little delay.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main()
{
    UCSR0B = 0;
    DDRD = 0b11111111;

    unsigned char upDown=1; // start going with the ports up
    unsigned char cylon=0;  // says which LED is on

    for(;;)
    {
        if(upDown==1){
            cylon++;
            if(cylon>=7) upDown=0;      // Reached the last LED
        }
        else {
            cylon--;
            if(cylon==0) upDown=1;      // Reached min LED
        }
            PORTD = 1 << cylon;
            _delay_ms(100);             // a little wait
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to turn on the n'th bit of `PORTD`.

`PORTD |= (1<<n);`

Where the bits are numbered 0, 1, 2, etc from right to left.

To turn off the 4th bit you would do

`PORTD &= ~(1<<4);`

Answer (score 0):

`PORTD = PORTD << 1` should work.

There's also a `<<=` operator that works like `+=`:

```
PORTD <<= 1;
```

But if the first version *seems* not to, methinks you have made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: I will add all my code in the question, cause your option isn't working somehow.